# Can vagrant cache files used within chef scripts in way similar way to vagrant boxes?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

When you download a vagrant box. The first time it has to download from a server. Then it caches that box for future use.

Is there a way to do this for files within a chef script. For example we use wget to pull down a zip file for some software. These usually take 40 minutes. I would like to have this only download one time (for each unique version) and cache the file somewhere for global usage later. So that if I create another vagrant machine that references the same zip file, it will use the cached file instead of downloading again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you use `remote_file` resource, you can use the [vagrant-cachier plugin](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier) to cache the downloaded files to a synced folder from the host. Even with direct wget calls you could specify a [generic bucket](http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/buckets/generic) and download files there.

Another approach is to use a caching web proxy in your local network, on your host, or even on another VM (see [polipo-box](https://github.com/tmatilai/polipo-box) for an example), and use the [vagrant-proxyconf plugin](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf) to automate the configuration of the Vagrant VMs.

Comment: I think that cachier should work and I've tried but didn't get it to work as I expected. You first configure a sync'd folder to whatever local folder you want? Then config a generic bucket for wget and it should save to the vm's local folder that is synced to my host folder? I'm also not sure on the scope to use for cachier as it doesn't really seem to matter.